# Using AspectJ/AJDT in RAD 7.5.5

Tags: aspectj, rad, ajdt

I'm using RAD 7.5.5.  I installed AJDT plugin from the download site:
http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/34/update/

I converted one of the existing Java projects to an AspectJ project, added an aspect to print log statements on method start and end of a methodA(), rebuilt the project and deployed.

I'm getting the below exception when methodA() is called:

*Exception thrown : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/aspectj/runtime/reflect/Factory.makeMethodSig(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/aspectj/lang/reflect/MethodSignature;*

I googled and found this could be caused because of an older version of aspectjrt.jar.  But RAD extends Eclipse 3.4 and hence I added the version of AJDT plugin that is compatible with Eclipse 3.4 (/RAD 7.5.5).  Any pointers to what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that aspectjrt.jar is on your classpath.  Also, make sure that it is the aspectjrt.jar that comes with AJDT.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Andrew. I added the aspectjrt.jar (that comes with AJDT) to the classpath of the server and restarted the server.  Also made sure that the same jar file is in the project's build path as well.  But that didn't help.  I still get the same issue.

Comment: Based on this post here: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg12131.html, it looks like you are somehow using AspectJ 1.2.1 on the server.  This looks like a workaround: "If you *really* need to run with that old crappy runtime, you can supply "-Xajruntimetarget:1.2", then it will produce code that will run against it, but I wouldn't recommend it..."

Comment: I got this from the manifest file present inside the jar file (from AJDT plugin folder):
`Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: org/aspectj/lang/
Specification-Title: AspectJ Runtime Classes 
Specification-Version: 1.6
Specification-Vendor: aspectj.org
Implementation-Title: org.aspectj.tools
Implementation-Version: 1.6.6
Implementation-Vendor: aspectj.org
Bundle-Name: AspectJ Runtime
Bundle-Version: 1.6.6
Bundle-Copyright: (C) Copyright 1999-2001 Xerox Corporation, 2002 Palo 
  Alto Research Center, Incorporated (PARC), 2003-2009 Contributors. 
  All Rights Reserved.`

Comment: So it looks like I'm using AspectJ 1.6.6 only.

Comment: To add more context: We have roughly 100 projects in RAD.  The services are deployed in WAS and the portlets are deployed in WPS.  This is the first time we are trying to introduce aspectj (in one of the service projects).  So, I installed AJDT plugin in RAD and converted the project to an AspectJ project.  When I clean and build all the projects, I get some compilation errors (unresolved in imports).  This happens only after introducing AspectJ.  Then I build that one project alone, it gets compiled and woven file.  I have added the aspectjrt.jar to the classpaths of both WAS and WPS.